# UILabel updating text, but won't remove old text

Tags: ios, uilabel, updating

EDIT: I figured out that i needed to remove subviews, once the view did disappear

```
[[self.scrollView subviews]makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

My problem is that I have an `UILabel` which updates the text correctly, but won't remove the old text. I think maybe it's because there are 2 `UILabels` on top of each other, here is a picture of it:

[image]

And here is my code. I can't see where the duplicate is:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.count; i++) {

    NSNumber *myNumber = [myscoretext objectAtIndex:i];
    float myScore = myNumber.floatValue;

    NSNumber *levelNumber = [neededscoretext objectAtIndex:i];
    float levelScore = levelNumber.floatValue;

    for (int i = 0; i < array1.count; i++) {

    NSNumber *myNumber = [myscoretext objectAtIndex:i];
    float myScore = myNumber.floatValue;

    NSNumber *levelNumber = [neededscoretext objectAtIndex:i];
    float levelScore = levelNumber.floatValue;

    float progressScore = ((float)myScore/(float)levelScore);


    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

    UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    NSArray *colorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:edmeral, turqouise, orange, red, nil];
    // Labeled progress views
    self.labeledProgressView = [[DALabeledCircularProgressView alloc]
                                initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25.0f, 20.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
    self.labeledProgressView.roundedCorners = NO;
    self.labeledProgressView.trackTintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.8];

    imageLevel = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25.0f, 20.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
    imageLevel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


    self.Scoreint = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-25.0f, 130, 195, 21)];
    self.Scoreint.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.Scoreint.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.Scoreint setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:15]];
    self.Scoreint.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    self.Scoreint.text = @"";


    if (myScore == 0) {

        NSString *scoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0 / %5ld", (long)levelScore];
        [self.Scoreint setText:scoreString];
    }
    else {

        NSString *scoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%5li / %5li", (long)myScore, (long)levelScore];
        [self.Scoreint setText:scoreString];

    }

    [subview addSubview:Scoreint];
```

I hope some of you guys can help me out with this! :)

Comment: Make UILabel's instance local one as same object getting added in each instance.

Comment: Is your `[subview addSubview:Scoreint]` inside a `for` loop?

Comment: Only initialise the label and add as a subview inside a if-statement: `if (!self.Scoreint) { ... }`. Also, think about your naming convention (should be `scoreInt`).

Answer (score 1):

the other way, you should do it, it's remove the label from superView everytime, before you initialize it.

You modify the code like this,

```
if(self.Scoreint) {
[self.Scoreint removeFromSuperview];
}
self.Scoreint = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-25.0f, 130, 195, 21)];
self.Scoreint.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.Scoreint.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.Scoreint setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:15]];
self.Scoreint.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.Scoreint.text = @"";
```

Answer (score 0):

that happens because you instantiate the UILabel each time, You have to instantiate the it only once, outside the for loop, and then just change the title.

This might work, i haven't tried it

```
self.Scoreint = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-25.0f, 130, 195, 21)];
self.Scoreint.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.Scoreint.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.Scoreint setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:15]];
self.Scoreint.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.Scoreint.text = @"";

for (int i = 0; i < array1.count; i++) {

NSNumber *myNumber = [myscoretext objectAtIndex:i];
float myScore = myNumber.floatValue;

NSNumber *levelNumber = [neededscoretext objectAtIndex:i];
float levelScore = levelNumber.floatValue;

for (int i = 0; i < array1.count; i++) {

NSNumber *myNumber = [myscoretext objectAtIndex:i];
float myScore = myNumber.floatValue;

NSNumber *levelNumber = [neededscoretext objectAtIndex:i];
float levelScore = levelNumber.floatValue;

float progressScore = ((float)myScore/(float)levelScore);


CGRect frame;
frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

NSArray *colorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:edmeral, turqouise, orange, red, nil];
// Labeled progress views
self.labeledProgressView = [[DALabeledCircularProgressView alloc]
                            initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25.0f, 20.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
self.labeledProgressView.roundedCorners = NO;
self.labeledProgressView.trackTintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.8];

imageLevel = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25.0f, 20.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
imageLevel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


[self.Scoreint setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:15]];
self.Scoreint.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.Scoreint.text = @"";


if (myScore == 0) {

    NSString *scoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0 / %5ld", (long)levelScore];
    [self.Scoreint setText:scoreString];
}
else {

    NSString *scoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%5li / %5li", (long)myScore, (long)levelScore];
    [self.Scoreint setText:scoreString];

}

[subview addSubview:Scoreint];
```

Comment: But i have to initialize it because i'm having an uiscrollview with different views inside, which i add the scoring label to at each view

Comment: then why don't you use an collectionView with customCells, and in each cell modify the label's title?

Answer (score 0):

In similar situation, the property of UIView’s visual appearance helped me. Try this:

```
self.Scoreint.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = true
```